# Which Windows bin/executable/process calls my startup programs?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I wish to know which process from Windows boot calls my startup programs, included in

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- `Start\All Programs\Initialize folder`

I cant find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explorer.exe starts all of those. You can verify with Process Explorer by looking at the process tree or the parent process.